# word-press dashboard isn't showing at all even after re-installing word-press

Tags: wordpress

- **word-press dashboard isn't showing at all, I tried re-installing

  word-press, it didn't show, any suggestions?**

---

Comment: What do you see, any error messages. Have you tried moving the plugins from the plugins folder via FTP incase there is a conflict?

Comment: how can we help with just this information?

Comment: Hello @Nova and welcome to stackoverflow, please refer to the questions guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask better questions and thus receive better answerrs